# How do I print previous specific word

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file called `city.txt`, which contains following entries.

```
Los Santos
San Fierro
Las Venturas
```

I want to print word before **r** in **San Fierro**, so the output would be like this.

```
San Fier
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: So the portion before last `r`? in all lines?

Comment: Can do both? Before **r** in San fier**r**o and in all lines

Comment: All lines that contain word **r** in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print everything up to the last `r`:

```
grep -o '^.*r' city.txt
```

To print everyting up to the first `r`:

```
grep r city.txt | grep -o '^[^r]*'
```

`-o` only prints the matching part of each line. `[^r]` matches anything but `r`.

If you only want the first match, add `-m1` to the last grep in each case.

Comment: Can you make the output show `San Fier` only ?

Comment: @Motiun: Do you mean you only want the first such line?

Answer (score 4):

To print the portion before last `r`, and print those lines only:

- `grep` with PCRE:

  ```
  grep -Po '.*(?=r)'
  ```

  `.*` matches greedily and the zero width positive lookahead pattern `(?=r)` makes sure the match is followed by `r`
- With `sed`:

  ```
  sed -n 's/r[^r]*$//p'
  ```

  `r[^r]*$` matches the portion from last `r` till end, and replaced with null.
- With `awk`:

  ```
  awk '/r/ {sub("r[^r]*$", ""); print}'
  ```

  Same as `sed`'s one, `/r/` makes sure we are operating on only lines containing `r`

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                     
Los Santos
San Fierro
Las Venturas

% grep -Po '.*(?=r)' city.txt                
San Fier
Las Ventu

% sed -n 's/r[^r]*$//p' city.txt                   
San Fier
Las Ventu

% awk '/r/ {sub("r[^r]*$", ""); print}' city.txt
San Fier
Las Ventu
```

Comment: Can you make the output show `San Fier` only ?

Answer (score 2):

Show everything before **r** in every line (lines that does not contains **r** will be ignored):

```
sub@debianmin:~$ grep r  city.txt | cut -f 1 -d r
San Fie
Las Ventu
```

---

If you only want **San Fie** use this command:

```
sub@debianmin:~$ grep r  city.txt | cut -f 1 -d r | head -n 1
San Fie
```

Comment: I want the output show `San Fier` only

Answer (score 1):

In grep, using Perl lookahead:

```
grep -Po '.*(?=r)'
```

This looks for a string followed by an `r`, but the `r` itself is not matched.

Comment: Can you make the output show `San Fier` only ?

Comment: @Motiun out of all those lines, you want only San Fier as the output?

Comment: Yeah, how to do it ?

Comment: @Motiun what part of San Fierro makes it special out of the other lines?

Comment: Nothing much, just wanted to know how.

Comment: @Motiun Why not just do `grep -o 'San Fier'` then?

Comment: Your command works perfectly, but I need to exclude the Las venturas output, is this possible ? (Sorry for late answer)

Comment: @Motiun and that's my question: what's the criteria you use to exclude that or include San Fiero?